# Mass, Time, Distance, a lunkhead Digital designer, and a question I really should know the answer to

Tags: energy, work

- I'm an engineer, but I'm an electronics designer, and mechanical
  math makes my head hurt. So, yes, I should be able to figure this out
  using my college textbooks, but I was never that good of a student.
- My wife and I have started wearing backpacks on our daily walks,
  and we're trying to come up with a non-calculus way to score a walk
  such that the score goes up if we carry more weight, walk faster, or
  walk further. In layman's terms, "work performed"... although in
  physics that is not the correct term.
- So, given that we have a Mass, a Distance, a Time, what should we use? If we calculate Kinetic
  Energy, we get an instantaneous value that we'd have to integrate, if
  we try to calculate Work we have to consider our acceleration, which
  again means we're going to be doing calculus... and this all makes me
  want to grab a bourbon.
- In a related question, I can't tell if I'm overthinking it, or if I
  just figured out something brilliant, but when M/S^2 is used for
  acceleration (such as in Work), can I actually just square the number
  of seconds it took me to walk the total number of meters? Because,
  the units work, but that would give me a really tiny number.

So... what do you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Acceleration and thus increased KE only occur when you first start walking. Once you are moving at a steady pace you are no longer accelerating or increasing KE,  if you move up or down hill  your gravitational potential energy does change. You may have better luck asking on https://fitness.stackexchange.com/   or perhaps by estimating calories burned

Comment: > if you move up or down hill
By chance, the area we walk regularly is rather flat city terrain... for certain, hills would complicate things.

>calories burned
The problem with this is, as we get into better shape, calories burned goes DOWN. It also considers our body mass, i burn roughly 2x more calories than my wife in basic activities. It's silly, I know, but we're trying to score our weighted backpacks, not our fat asses. :-)

>fitness.stackexchange
I figure, if I'm bad at math, a bunch of personal trainers may not be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reward distance, speed, and weight, so it seems simple to start by multiplying them together: $Score=D*D/T*W=D^2W/T$.  But while it's logical to score zero if your distance is zero, it's less logical to score zero if you do a long walk with no weight.  Also, if you're much bigger than your wife, she should probably score more for carrying the same weight. Accordingly, I propose that weight, $W$, be replaced with a factor like $[1 + \frac{4W}{W_{body}}]$; that way you double your unburdened score if you carry a quarter of your body weight, $W_{body}$.  So here is a metric for your consideration: $$\frac{D^2}{T}(1 + \frac{4W}{W_{body}})$$ If you use units of meters squared per second, the scores are high, probably over a thousand for a typical walk. But if you use instead km squared per hour, they are nice enough: if you go 3 km in half an hour with no weight, you score 18.

Comment: Not a bad idea!

It occurs to me, there is a constant deceleration acting on us when we walk,because when we stop walking, we stop moving... there must be a way to quantify this.

It's always bugged me that physics doesn't seem to have a way to quantify walking in a loop at a constant speed... Ah well... Thanks again!